# How To Do Elastic Search In Model And Related Models In Django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using `django_elasticsearch_dsl` which is running on `9200` port number 
and i have two models.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
```

**document.py**

```
@posts.doc_type
class PostDocument(DocType):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name'
        ]
        related_models = [Category]

        def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
            """If related_models is set, define how to retrieve the book instance(s) from the related model."""
            if isinstance(related_instance, Category):
                return related_instance.book_set.all()
```

**search.py**

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Q
p = Q("multi_match", query=request.GET.get('q'), fields=['name','categories__name'],
                  type='phrase_prefix')
s = PostDocument.search().query(p)
result = s.execute()
```

this search code only works for the books models and i am unable to retrieve using related Category model

my required output should be 
like i have two books like `jungle` and `cuop`
and jungle book linked to  `Category` model (Category name is `sport`)

so if search `?q=ju` output should show only `jungle` (working with above code)
and if search    `?q=sport` output should show only `jungle` this is **not** working(it is not giving any results)